# How we can fetch code from Gitlab when create image using packer?

Tags: packer

I am creating image using packer. I have used 2 provisioners i.e `Shell` and `ansible-local` and both are working fine and installed all the required packages.

But now i need to deploy my application code too into my image which is over Gitlab.
I am out of idea how we can do this. Can you please help me how we can fetch the code from Gitlab to create image using packer?

Any assistance will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can anybody help me on above issue?

Answer (score 1):

You should use *ssh agent forwarding*.

1. On the host running Packer load a ssh key that have access to git repository `ssh-add <path to private key>`.
2. Ensure that you have `"ssh_disable_agent_forwarding": false` (default) in your packer template. See [Docs: Communicator](https://packer.io/docs/templates/communicator.html#ssh_disable_agent_forwarding).

Now in your packer provisioning script you should be able to clone the repository over SSH with `git clone git@<GitLab server>:<repo.git>`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have follow the steps suggested by you. I have created another `.yml` to execute git clone as deploy user. But still i am getting permission denied error. I have access over that repository and i have added my private SSH  key as per step1. Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you please help me to fix the above issue? I have follow the steps suggested by you but still getting `permission denied ` error. We can't use HTTP(S) method because its disable at our Gitlab. So we can use only SSH option.

Comment: Ask on the Packer mailing list, https://groups.google.com/group/packer-tool and describe your configuration and what steps you have taken to troubleshoot this.