# Git clone operation in packer

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, packer

I am new in devops. I want to deploy my three application in AWS ec2 in particular location such as /var/apps. To do this I want to make packer image using ansible provisoner to set up nodejs, pm2 and nginx. Is it possible to make packer image with bitbucket source code using git clone? As I can use this image to write terraform script for AWS autoscaling.

Comment: This may be too broad and opinion based for stack overflow. It sounds like you need to find a tutorial etc.

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/q/53826216/226174

Comment: See my answer there https://stackoverflow.com/a/53897443/226174